# Powershell Stop Service with timeout function

Tags: powershell, service

I would like to use a function to stop a service and kill it if necessarry:

```
function StopService([string] $name)  {
$Time = Get-Date
$svc = Get-Service -Name $name
$timespan = New-Object -TypeName System.Timespan -ArgumentList 0,0,60
try 
    {
        $svc.Stop()
        $svc.WaitForStatus([ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped, $timespan)
        "[OK] - $Time - Service $name stopped" | out-file -FilePath $LogFile -append -Encoding Ascii
    }
catch 
    {
    $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "name = '$name'"
    try 
        {
            Stop-Process -Id $Service.processid -Force -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
            "[WARNING] - $Time - Service $name stopped by killing the process" | out-file -FilePath $LogFile -append -Encoding Ascii
        }
    catch 
        {
            "[ERROR] - $Time - Service $name could not be stopped or is not found" | out-file -FilePath $LogFile -append -Encoding Ascii
        }
    }
}
```

It seem that it skips the "waitforstatus" and goes straight to the catch clause. The rest is working fine but I would like to wait at least 60 seconds before killing the process by its ID

Comment: The issue comes most likely from `Stop()`, the issue is that you have decided to not use the exception to have a better understanding when debugging. Your `catch` block should include at least `$_.Exception.Message` to better understand why the code failed.

Comment: "[...] and goes straight to the catch clause" - that indicates either `$svc.Stop()` or `$svc.WaitForStatus(...)` throws an exception. Inspect `$_` inside the `catch` clause to find out why

Comment: Aside - might be worth passing all your logging logic through a custom ```Write-Log -Level Warning -Message “my log msg”``` cmdlet so you can just call that instead of the long ```”my log msg” | out-file …``` command every time. That can also call Get-Date so you get the exact timestamp - at the moment your timestamp gets progressively more stale because you snapshot it at the start of your function. Also makes it easier to change logging (event viewer, database, app insights, raygun, or text vs structured logging, etc) as the logging *implementation* is centralised…